# What is a scipy.sparse matrix in the CSR format?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

Im new with scikit and scipy and i tried the following:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher
data = [[('this', 'is'), ('is', 'a'), ('a', 'text')],
        [('and', 'one'), ('one', 'more')],]

fh = FeatureHasher(input_type='string')
X = fh.transform(((' '.join(x) for x in sample) for sample in data))
print X
```

The problem is that i dont understand the output:

```
  (0, 18882)    1.0
  (0, 908056)   1.0
  (0, 1003453)  1.0
  (1, 433727)   1.0
  (1, 575892)   -1.0
```

Could anybody explain me what does this output means?. I read the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) of the FeatureHasher() method but didnt understad it.

Comment: Check this link [ML-Hashing](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73325/understanding-feature-hashing)

Answer (score 2):

This is the display of a large sparse matrix, as implemented in `scipy.sparse`.

```
  (0, 18882)    1.0
  (0, 908056)   1.0
  (0, 1003453)  1.0
  (1, 433727)   1.0
  (1, 575892)   -1.0
```

`X.shape` will give the dimensions of it.  `X.todense()` produces a regular `numpy` matrix, with a lot of zero values.

Here's a sample of a much smaller sparse matrix:

```
In [182]: from scipy import sparse
In [183]: X=sparse.csr_matrix([[0,1,2],[1,0,0]])
In [184]: X
Out[184]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [185]: print X
  (0, 1)    1
  (0, 2)    2
  (1, 0)    1
In [186]: X.todense()
Out[186]: 
matrix([[0, 1, 2],
        [1, 0, 0]])
In [187]: X.toarray()
Out[187]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

The `print X` shows the nonzero values of this matrix, in the `(row, col) value` format.

Your `X` is at least a `(2,1003454)` matrix, but mostly zeros.